# Python: how to ping a server?

Tags: python

How do I ping a server from within Python?

I am trying to get a ping script working. I am using pxssh to login to a server and once logged in, pinging an IP address. I need to check if there is any loss etc..Below is my script but an seeing some error..Can anyone help. I am using sendline to send commands to the server.

```
s= pxssh.pxssh()
class DhcpServer:

        def connect(self,**kwargs):
                self.dhcp_server = kwargs.get('dhcp_server',None)
                self.username = kwargs.get('user_name', None)
                self.password = kwargs.get('password',None)
                s.login(self.dhcp_server,self.username,self.password)
                print "Connected to server"

def pingGW(self):
                s.sendline('ping 127.0.0.1 -c 5 > /etc/dhcp/ping.txt')
                s.prompt()
                s.sendline('cd/etc/dhcp/')
                s.prompt()

                str = '100% packet loss'
                jes = open((s.sendline('vi /etc/dhcp/ping.txt')), 'r')
                for line in jes:
                        if re.search(str, line):
                                print 'Cannot reach the gateway'
```

after correct indendation:

```
def pingGW(self):
                s.sendline('ping 127.0.0.1 -c 5 > /etc/dhcp/ping.txt')
                s.prompt()
                s.sendline('cd /etc/dhcp/')
                s.prompt()

                str = '100% packet loss'
                jes = open((s.sendline('vi /etc/dhcp/ping.txt')), 'r')
                for line in jes:
                        if re.search(str, line):
                                print 'Cannot reach the gateway'

                print "Ping success"
```

Error message :

jes = open((s.sendline('vi /etc/dhcp/ping.txt')), 'r') TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found [jesgeorg@ins-qasvr-18 lib]$

Comment: could you post the error?

Comment: The `def pingGW` is not correctly indented.

Comment: I am not familiar with pxssh but your `pingGW()` method is not indented properly and `sendline('cd')` command needs a space between cd and path.

Comment: jes = open((s.sendline('vi /etc/dhcp/ping.txt')), 'r')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
[jesgeorg@ins-qasvr-18 lib]$

Comment: I indended the pingGW correctly now

Comment: I think i know the mistake.. s.sendline('vi /etc/dhcp/ping.txt')) returns an interger not a string file.. how can i open the file otherwise?

Comment: use "cat /etc/dhcp/ping.txt | grep '100% packet loss'". If the return value of grep command is zero, then do `echo error in pinging....`. Grep returns a non-zero error code if it doesnt find a  match

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in pinging from within python:

```
import ping
ping.verbose_ping("example.com")
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ping/0.2

Regarding your original question, sendline() does not do what you think.  It writes to a "pseudoterminal" session, just as if someone were typing.  You don't need to do this to open the file.

If you want to open the file, just

```
fd = open('/etc/dhcp/ping.txt')
```

Comment: I need to use sendline() to send commands to the server. The ping.txt file is stored inside the /etc/dhcp flder INSIDE the server. If i do a normal fd =open(//etc/dhcp..') it wouldn't open the file from the server.. it will look at the local machine.. which is not what i want